# I try to setup zabbix server on CentOS 6 (close system) but can find zabbix-server binary file after run rpm install rpm package

Tags: centos, software-installation, zabbix

I am trying to set up zabbix on CentOS 6 in closed system (one with no internet connection). I can only put rpm(s) to that machine, and run command the command:

```
rpm -ivh zabbix-2.2.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

After that's done, I cannot find any binary or executable file in /var/run/zabbix or any zabbix related folder. Anyone know where is it installed?

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix has much more than that one single RPM.

This is the list from my Zabbix server -

```
zabbix22-2.2.1-5.el6.x86_64
zabbix22-web-2.2.1-5.el6.noarch
zabbix22-agent-2.2.1-5.el6.x86_64
zabbix22-dbfiles-pgsql-2.2.1-5.el6.noarch
zabbix22-server-2.2.1-5.el6.noarch
zabbix22-web-mysql-2.2.1-5.el6.noarch
zabbix22-server-pgsql-2.2.1-5.el6.x86_64
zabbix22-web-pgsql-2.2.1-5.el6.noarch
```

Zabbix is a web based monitoring tool. It also uses a SQL backend to store metrics, host information, etc etc.

You'll at least need some of those packages that I have installed to use Zabbix, namely the `zabbix22-web`, `zabbix22-web-pgsql` or `zabbix22-web-mysql`, and `zabbix22-server`.

If I recall correctly, those are the minimum packages needed.
Have you looked through the [Zabbix Doco](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/doku.php?id=2.2/manual) ?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I think zabbix has more than one rpm as you said. But I so curious that after I try 
>>> rpm -ivh zabbix-2.2.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
I only get zabbix folders but does not have binary file in them.

Comment: then I try 
>>> rpm -ivh zabbix-server-mysql-2.2.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
warning: zabbix-server-mysql-2.2.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: 
error: Failed dependencies:
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        libodbc.so.2()(64bit) is needed by zabbix-server-mysql-2.2.3-1.el6.x86_64
        zabbix-server = 2.2.3-1.el6 is needed by zabbix-server-mysql-2.2.3-1.el6.x86_64
I have doubt about last line that complain about zabbix-server binary not found.

Comment: Zabbix relies on a database to work. To install that package, you'll need to install all the required dependencies.

Comment: Ah I see, But I am thinking about build vmware or virtual host of CentOS with internet connection, yum install them in normal way. Then copy binary to my target machine. Is it a good idea?

Comment: I would just connect the target machine to the internet and use yum to install it. Much simpler than trying to work out dependencies yourself. Alternatively, if you don't want to do that, I would use a CentOS host with an internet connection to download the relevant packages, then transfer the packages over, not the binaries.

Comment: That's quite good idea, thank Lawrence :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a REPO directory where you'll place all the downloaded packages. Then use

```
yum --disablerepo=<name_of_your_repo> install createrepo
```

To create the local REPO, you can do:

`vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Local.repo`

You can edit this file entering the info needed. As an example:

```
name=name_of_your_repo
baseurl=file:///usr/local/path_dir_for_your_repo/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Save the file and run this on the terminal:

```
createrepo /usr/local/path_dir_for_your_repo/
```

Then they will show up on `yum`

```
yum list available
```

Then you can install zabbix with its dependencies just by using `yum` normally.

For example, you can use this first:

```
yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel net-snmp-devel curl-devel ntp openssh-clients
```

And finally easily install the zabbix components:

```
yum install zabbix zabbix-agent zabbix-get zabbix-web zabbix-server
```